# Edit many xml file names and contents at once with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to write a bash script to change an xml file name and contents within this XML file for over 500 different folders.

I'd prefer to use the `sed` command for this process with a bash script instead of using `xmlstarlet` as I don't want to install it on this VM. The directory is a little annoying as the xml file is the same name as a previous directory.

This is an example of a file to be modified:

```
/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/junk/VFS/junk.xml
                                   ^^^^     ^^^^
```

With `junk.xml` containing a line:

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/junk/</url>
                                    ^^^^
```

I would like to rename the file to the following:

```
/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/junk/VFS/treasure.xml
                                   ^^^^     ^^^^^^^^
```

With `junk.xml` containing the modified line:

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/treasure/</url>
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

The `customerlogin.csv` is comma delimited with column A = `junk` and column B = `treasure` as my test example.

```
while IFS=, read -r orig new; do
find "/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/"$orig"/VFS/" -name "$orig" -execdir mv -n -- {} "$new" \;
sed -i 's#/"$org"#$new"#' "$new".xml
done < customerlogin.csv
```

I'm new to bash and scripting. I expect I can't reference the .xml file like above and nothing occurs when I run the script.

Comment: First try something for one file (without `-i`). You read the var `orig` and use `$org`, The parameters in `sed` are enclosed in single quotes, so they will not be evaluated.

Comment: What happens if `find` doesn't find the desired XML file? or do you know, for a fact, that all entries from `customerlogin.csv` have a matching XML file? if you know for a fact the XML file does in fact exist then remove the `find` call and have `sed` (remove the `-i)` read the 'orig' file and write the output to the 'new' file; once you've verified the 'new' file contents are correct you can `rm` the 'orig' file; I recommend this approach since *a)* you're new to bash and *b)* your `sed` script doesn't do what you think; if you use `sed -i` and screw up your files you now have a bigger mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a starting point at least:

```
dir='/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/'
while IFS=, read -r oldStr newStr; do

    oldFile="$dir/$oldStr/VFS/${oldStr}.xml"
    newFile="$dir/$oldStr/VFS/${newStr}.xml"

    if [[ -f "$oldFile" ]] && [[ ! -f "$newFile" ]]; then
        sed "s:/$oldStr/:/$newStr/:" "$oldFile" > "$newFile" &&
        rm -f "$oldFile"
    fi

done < customerlogin.csv
```

That assumes your `oldStr` and `newStr` strings dont' contain regexp metachars or backreference metachars, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed), and that `oldStr` only occurs in the location where you want to change it in the files.

Comment: Hello dear Ed, please come over here and let us enjoy one of your masterpieces :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293902/macos-terminal-split-csv-file-by-column-1-value/77294227

Comment: @Freeman idk about "masterpiece" but I threw some code at it :-).

Comment: Hello Ed, this worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @EdMorton I'm trying to implement this with a slight change. I got 3 columns in the csv.

_ dir='/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/'
while IFS=, read -r oldStr midStr newStr; do

    oldFile="$dir/$oldStr/VFS/${midStr}.xml"
    newFile="$dir/$oldStr/VFS/${newStr}.xml"

    if [[ -f "$oldFile" ]] && [[ ! -f "$newFile" ]]; then
        sed "s:/$midStr/:/$newStr/:" "$oldFile" > "$newFile" &&
        rm -f "$oldFile"
    fi

done < customerlogin.csv _

When trying to do this, it works perfectly if oldStr & midStr don't match. If they do, xml file wont edit. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Trevor please ask a new question with it's own [mcve].

Comment: @EdMorton That'd work much better, I've posted it. I've tried for days and can't seem to get it to work the way I want. Thanks!