# Edit folder and xml files at once with comma delimited csv using sed

Tags: xml, bash, shell, csv, sed

I'm trying to write a Bash script to change an XML file name and contents within this XML file for over 500 different folders. A member of the community helped with [the first iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77290645/1745001) of this wonderful script.

I'd prefer to use the `sed` command for this process with a Bash script instead of using `xmlstarlet` as I don't want to install it on this VM. The directory is a little annoying as I'm trying to change a few things at the same time.

This is an example of a file to be modified:

```
/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/junk/VFS/junk2.xml
                                   ^^^^     ^^^^^
```

With `junk2.xml` containing a line:

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/junk2/</url>
                                    ^^^^^
```

I would like to rename the file to the following:

```
/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/junk/VFS/treasure.xml
                                   ^^^^     ^^^^^^^^
```

With newly named `treasure.xml` containing the modified line:

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/treasure/</url>
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

The `customerlogin.csv` is comma delimited with column oldStr = `junk` and column midStr = `junk2` and column newStr = `treasure` as my test example.

CSV Example

```
junk,junk2,treasure
help,helpful,helping
old,middle,new
dog,dog,cat
```

```
dir='/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/' 
while IFS=, read -r oldStr midStr newStr; do 
       oldFile="$dir/$oldStr/VFS/${midStr}.xml" 
       newFile="$dir/$oldStr/VFS/${newStr}.xml" 

    if [[ -f "$oldFile" ]] && [[ ! -f "$newFile" ]]; 
    then
        sed "s:/$midStr/:/$newStr/:" "$oldFile" > "$newFile" && 
        rm -f "$oldFile" 
    fi 
done < customerlogin.csv
```

When I run the script, it works exactly how I would like if all three columns are different names. However, if Column A (`oldStr`) and Column B (`midStr`) happen to have the same value such as (dog) & (dog), the XML file name will change to cat but the XML contents remain unchanged as dog.

Result I recieve if (`oldStr`) value equals (`midStr`)

```
/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/dog/VFS/cat.xml
                                   ^^^     ^^^
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/dog</url>
                                    ^^^
```

Result I recieve if (`oldStr`) value does not equal (`midStr`)

```
/var/opt/FTPserver/users/MainUsers/help/VFS/helpful.xml
                                   ^^^^     ^^^^^^^
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/helping</url>
                                    ^^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure what is causing this and how I would go about fixing it.

Comment: Could you share a small sample CSV file to better show us what it looks like?

Comment: I don't see a way to share a CSV file in the comments, so I'll edit in a small sample CSV file in the question.

Comment: In general, using `sed` or other syntax-unaware tools to edit XML or JSON is bad practice -- there's a lot of context-dependent escaping/unescaping/etc needed when inserting data into an XML file. If I actually had this task, I'd be using Python (which has both CSV and XML libraries included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is looking for `/dog/` but your XML files have `/dog<` instead (note the absence of a `/` between `/dog` and `</url>`):

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/dog</url>
```

so that regexp won't match regardless of whether `$oldStr` == `$midStr` or not (and so it's not true that `helpful` is becoming `helping` in the file as you show).

In your previous question when trying to match `/junk`/ you had input files that looked like (note the `/` between `/junk` and `</url>`):

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/junk/</url>
```

so if your current XML files followed that same format now then the file would look like (note the `/` now between `/dog` and `</url>`):

```
<url>file://home/FTPserver/Customer/dog/</url>
```

so `/dog/` would be present, match the regexp, and be replaced.

If there may or may not be a `/` before the `<`, but there's always the `<`, in the files you want to modify then change this:

```
sed "s:/$midStr/:/$newStr/:"
```

to this, using GNU or BSD sed for `-E`:

```
sed -E "s:/$midStr(/?<):/$newStr\1:"
```

Comment: Double checking the xml file contents...There is a discrepancy between some files that do have the /$newStr/</url> and other /$newStr</url>. So the code provided is working as intended with if there is a / before </url> but not if it's missing a /.  I'm now perplexed why is there a discrepancy between xml files for this ftp server.

Comment: Your suggestion of GNU/BSD is perfect Ed. That did the trick. Thank you again for your time and help, I really appreciate it! Have a great holidays

Comment: You're welcome and you too.